# Does not read CSS file, JS and images on the phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I'm new to this site and I encountered a problem that I can't figure out. After I did part of my site I decided to upload the files to my phone and analyze what needs to be changed. The problem is that it doesn't want to to read the CSS file or the JS file including the images. I looked over the previous topics with a similar problem but it didn't work. I do not know what to do.Errors only appear on my phone.Help and Thanks!

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Prajiturele</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE64C.jpg

Comment: Probably the path css /style.css is not under your html file. Can you show your file tree?

Comment: If you already have host set up for your site, open it from there on your phone. If you don't,  read up on how to set up a localhost server and how to connect to it using your phone usb connected to your computer

Comment: @user2719361 look file tree https://imgur.com/a/kGA4wox

Answer (score 0):

if it does not read the CSS file you can use this:

For images, the <img src="(link of your image")>

Check the URL or the title of your CSS files. Do they exactly match? If so, it can be a result of typo errors.

Comment: Everything is fine. I want to mention that I also used an older site that worked. Today, that site doesn't work on the phone either

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the src of your JS script and CSS layout ?
There might be a problem in links you use

Comment: Yes, I checked carefully

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded an Html Reader and I see that it reads it very well. While in the browser in Firefox or chrome does not read